# Why are these two titles together: Mr. President

Tags: forms-of-address

They both are titles- Mr. and President. But, Mr. President is a valid address to Mr. Barack Obama. Is it grammatically okay?

I am also confused what if there is a lady president. How do we address her?

Comment: This is an interesting question, especially the latter part! :) +1

Comment: You said that it is "valid", but you don't know if it's "grammatically correct". It seems you are *saying* that it is correct and then *asking* if it is correct. Can you make your question more clear, if possible? It is correct in every way, but I don't know what to say about "why". The equivalent manner of address for a woman is "Madam President", though I'm sure if a female president preferred to be called "Ms. President", people would do so. "Mrs. President" would likely be avoided due to potential confusion resulting from traditional uses of *Mrs.* which are tied to a husband's title.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com).  According to Wikipedia, [similar usages go back to 1376](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._President_%28title%29).  I have also read that this is a tradition descended from how a congressman greeted President Washington shortly after he became president.  According to Wikipedia, Washington wanted a ridiculously grandiose title.  My impression is that most Americans thought humble titles were honorable.

Comment: @jasper fascinating! Growing up, I had always heard that Washington wanted to avoid grandiose titles so that they wouldn't become the tyranny they sought to escape from. Even though that doesn't make any sense, I believed it all. Apparently the exact opposite is true, as they were worried "his highness" or "his majesty" isn't grandiose enough.

Comment: @Jasper I don't believe that detail about George Washington. I don't believe Washington wanted a grandiose title. Remember that Washington refused to run for a third term; thus, the two-term limit for the Office of the President.

Comment: @hfontanez it wasn't actually a formalized limit until 1951, though, presidents up until then (other than Roosevelt) **chose** not to run for a third term.

Comment: I would actually argue that using "Mr. President" would give the deference to the station, rather than the person.  **Who** is the president is important but the **station** is what deserves the respect... and that remains regardless of who is in the position.

Comment: @Catija you are correct about the formalization, but that's not what I am talking about. The tradition, and subsequently the 22nd amendment were inspired by Washington's refusal to serve a 3rd term. That is what I am saying. Therefore, I doubt that Washington, who refuse to take over this "grandiose" position, wanted a "grandiose" title like Jasper suggested.  I don't believe  that was his character. That's all I am saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1337 is perfectly correct, to expand a bit...

**President** is both a title and a name substitute depending on how it's used:

> President Obama

In this case, **President** is a title and it applies to Obama.

> Mr. President

This is often (if not always) used when addressing the president directly (assuming you aren't a close friend or family). It is the equivalent of using "Your Honor" when addressing a judge. It is a polite way of addressing him without using his name, which might be a little informal.

Other options are:

> Mr. Obama

This is often used in news reporting to talk about the president.

> POTUS

Acronym for "President of the United States".  This is generic and applies to any currently sitting president.

In the case of a female president, the correct term would be:

> Madam President

This is just like [Nancy Pelosi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Pelosi) was "Madam Speaker" when she was Speaker of the House.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically okay. In this case, "Mr." is a **title** and "President" is a **name** (the name of an office position). As for a lady, she would be referred to as Madam President.

(or something like this)

Comment: it's mrs - check wikipedia